# When typing in input the page scrolls up on mobile?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, viewport-units

I am creating a One page website , each section takes up the whole viewport height and width (100vw & 100vw) , for mobile screens , I have used media queries to adjust the height so the content fits , the problem is , one section has a form and when the user types in the input , the page scrolls up or sometimes scrolls down?

I have no idea why this is happening?

The HTML for this form is:

```
    <section id="quote">
    <div id="ugallerys" class="uparrow"><img class="centerimage img-responsive" src="images/up.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="fwidth container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div id="contentquote">
                        <form method="POST" id="quoteform">
                            <div class="form centerfield">
                                <div class="heading white lesspace">Quote</div>
                                <hr>
                                <label for="Full Name">
                                    <h4 class="white center">Full Name</h4>
                                </label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control centerfield lwidth" id="name" onFocus="window.scrollTo(0, 0);" name="name" placeholder="e.g Tom Jones" />
                                <br />
                                <div class="centerfield lwidth">
                                    <label for="Book Out Date">
                                        <h4 class="white">Pickup Date</h4>
                                    </label>
                                    <input type="date" class="form-control" onFocus="window.scrollTo(0, 0);" id="bookoutdate" name="bookoutdate" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="centerfield lwidth">
                                    <label for="Book In Date">
                                        <h4 class="white">Dropoff Date</h4>
                                    </label>
                                    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="bookindate" name="bookindate" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="centerfield lwidth">
                                    <h1><span id="days">0</span> Days</h1>
                                    <hr>
                                </div>
                                <div class="centerfield lwidth">
                                    <label for="Age">
                                        <h4 class="white">Age</h4>
                                    </label>
                                    <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="e.g. 18" id="age" name="age" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="centerfield lwidth">
                                    <label for="Email">
                                        <h4 class="white">Email</h4>
                                    </label>
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="e.g. tomjones@demo.com" id="email" name="email" />
                                </div>
                                 <div class="centerfield lwidth">
                                    <label for="Contact">
                                        <h4 class="white">Contact Number</h4>
                                    </label>
                                    <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="e.g. 03375664399" id="number" name="number" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="centerfield lwidth">
                                    <label for="Comments">
                                        <h4 class="white">Comments</h4>
                                    </label>
                                    <textarea class="form-control" id="comments" name="comments"></textarea>
                                </div>
                                <div class="toppadding centerfield">
                                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" value="Send" name="submit" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="dcontact" class="downarrowsp3"><img class="centerimage img-responsive" src="images/down.png" />
    </div>
</section>
```

and the CSS for this section is:

```
    #quote {
    height: 210vh !important;
    overflow:hidden;
    width: 100vw !important;
    background-color: #000000;
    margin:0px !important;
    padding:0px !important;
    }
```

here is the link to the website itself: http://www.a1phantom.com/

Comment: Perhaps when the input receives focus, the screen viewport height decreases to make room for the keyboard, so each section reduces in height. So suppose the form is 800px down the page initially - when the keyboard appears, the form might be moved up to 600px because each section is shorter in height, but the viewport is still at 800px down the page so another part of the website is visible.

Comment: This sounds right,  so should I add jquery code to increase the height of the viewport when the input is foccused on?

Comment: Not sure if that can be done that way, because the viewport is controlled by the browser. If you made sure the height is fixed and not relative to the viewport that might solve the problem (e.g.: perhaps adjust the height of the sections to the pixel equivalent of 210vh or 100vh once after the page finishes loading)

Answer (score 0):

On your text field, you have the following action

```
<input type="text" class="form-control centerfield lwidth" id="name" 
onfocus="window.scrollTo(0, 0);" 
name="name" placeholder="e.g Tom Jones">
```

The attribute `onfocus="window.scrollTo(0, 0);"` is causing your page to scroll on focus of the text fields

Comment: Thanks , I have now removed this and the issue is fixed for desktop , but there is still a little scroll on mobile? I have a feeling it is something to do with the viewport sizing?

Comment: I think you just need to refresh, there is no scroll on my mobile browser

Comment: I think this is only happening on mobiles themselves and not web browsers running on  a desktop. The above suggestion of a keyboard might be the problem.